# Using Sapper, How to get the current page's slug in template.html

Tags: svelte-3, sapper

Going through the docs, it seems like Sapper's template.html only has these tags available:

```
%sapper.base%
%sapper.styles%
%sapper.head%
%sapper.html%
%sapper.scripts
```

What I'd love to have is the current page's slug to use it like so:

```html
  <!-- bottom of template.html -->

  <img src="https://piratepx.com/page={currentPageSlug}" 
    alt="" style="display:none;"/>
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't need to be available to JS, just added in the HTML.

I'm exporting to static and this would be a trivial task with most Static Site Generators but I can't find the obvious solution with Sapper.

Comment: What is stopping you from adding this in Svelte itself ?

Comment: Nothing, but I'd have to add it to every page rather than once. Plus, I'd rather have that image tag not rendered by JS, just HTML.
Sounds like you have an idea of how it could be done rather nicely though... feel free to answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you are using Sapper I would do this in `_layout.svelte` instead:

```html
<script>
 import { stores } from '@sapper/app';
 const { page } = stores();
 $: currentPageslug = $page.params.slug
</script>

<img src="https://piratepx.com/page={currentPageSlug}" alt=""/>
```

With this technique you can also add a default value, or some condition in case there is no slug.

Comment: It didn't work in _layout.svelte, but I applied the same logic in my footer and it works, even with JS disabled. Thanks!